# How to add category name for each product in shop page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbQAY.jpg)

how to add product category in product sheet of woocommerce archive page. Right now it shows "Title" "Price" and "Add to Cart Button".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these codes to your theme `functions.php` file. It will show category name above the title.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', function ( ){
    global $product;
    
    echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id());
}, 9 );
```